# How to save an image in Android without compressing?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Android application that captures images and stores them in the internal memory, but to save the images are compressed and I want to be saved in its original size without any compression.

This is the code I am using to store images, as I do so not me compress ??

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

File mypath = new File(directory, "TheChat" + (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) + "Avatar.jpg");

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What file format are you planning on using for the image? Most file formats used by programmers are compressed, such as PNG, JPEG, GIF, and WebP.

Comment: Why do you prefer no compression over lossless compression?

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a BLOB (bytearray), then reconvert it to a bitmap upon loading it. If it's for internal use only it should work fine. If you're not compressing it at all you might as well save it in a straight-forward format.